# Python - SqlAlchemy: convert lists of tuples to list of atomic values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

while working on my Python project (my first app), I ran into an issue when running a query against the database:
I get as a result a list of tuples containing a single value, like:
[(value1, ), (value2, )]
The tables involved have a Many to Many relationships, the ORM is SQLAlchemy.

My solution is to use a foreach loop:

```
def get_user_roles(user_id):

    the_roles = db.session.query(Role.role).filter(Role.users.any(id=user_id)).all()
    response = []
    length = len(the_roles)
    for key in range(length):
        the_roles[key] = list(the_roles[key])
        response.append(the_roles[key][0])

    return response
```

For a better understanding, you can have a look here: 
[https://github.com/Deviad/adhesive/blob/master/theroot/users_bundle/helpers/users_and_roles.py](https://github.com/Deviad/adhesive/blob/master/theroot/users_bundle/models/user.py)

I am looking for a better approach as I know that foreach loops are time-consuming.

Thank you.

Comment: why not `for role in the_roles`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, because I have a list of sets instead of a list of primitive type, atomic elements.

Comment: i don't see sets here

Comment: and list of sets is a list itself, i.e. iterable

Comment: @AzatIbrakov in fact as an error I get: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not result

Comment: please add what are you trying to do with traceback to question

Comment: @AzatIbrakov the result of the query from SQLAlchemy is something like  [(value1, ), (value2, )], as I said, id est a list of sets, not a list of values (integers, strings, etc.)

Comment: `tuple`s are not `set`s

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, pardon tuple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `the_roles` is the list of tuples with one element (in your example you obtain it from database, but it doesn't matter for `response` object generating) like

```
>>>the_roles = [(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,)]
```

then we can generate `response` object using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

```
>>>response = [value for (value,) in the_roles]
>>>response
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Finally your `get_user_role` can be rewritten like

```
def get_user_roles(user_id):
    the_roles = db.session.query(Role.role).filter(Role.users.any(id=user_id)).all()
    return [value for (value,) in the_roles]
```